# imagegif() strange fail

Tags: php, gd

Im creating images to output. When I call the final `imagegif()` I get the usual "the image sdfsdsdf cannot be displayed because it contains errors". But if I save this image by the 2nd parameter, it DOES result in a valid GIF image! And `imagegif()` returns true.
Now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I save this image by the 2nd parameter, it DOES result in a
>   valid GIF image! And imagegif() returns true. Now what?

Check the output of your script - it sends something else to the browser. Typically it could be error/warning/notice messages, text output from that script or from another one included into it, spaces/new lines or something else (like BOM record in case of UTF encoding in script file) before the `<?php` tag.

Solution is simple - comment the `header('Content-Type: image/gif');` and call script directly (not the page including the images generated by the script). Check for anything before the 'garbage' of the binary content of the image file itself.

You may need to add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the script in case error reporting/display is turned off as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you use imagegif() with one parameter then need to use and

```
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
```

becouse the image is displayed in browser , else the image is saved into file.